# FieldDefaulting handlers

Tags: acumatica

I am having trouble setting default values for a filter on a processing page.  I originally had code in the RowSelected handler to set the default values and set the end dates default as below:

```
//Local unbound filter DAC
#region StartShipDate
public abstract class startShipDate : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected DateTime? _StartShipDate;
[PXDate()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Ship Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = false)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual DateTime? StartShipDate { get; set; }
#endregion

#region EndShipDate
public abstract class endShipDate : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected DateTime? _EndShipDate;
[PXDate()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "End Ship Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual DateTime? EndShipDate { get; set; }
#endregion

#region StartImportDate
public abstract class startImportDate : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected DateTime? _StartImportDate;
[PXDate()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Import Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = false)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual DateTime? StartImportDate { get; set; }
#endregion

#region EndImportDate
public abstract class endImportDate : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected DateTime? _EndImportDate;
[PXDate()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "End Import Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
public virtual DateTime? EndImportDate { get; set; }
#endregion


//Excerpt from RowSelected handler
if (!filter.StartImportDate.HasValue && filter.EndImportDate.HasValue)
{
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime begDate = endDate.AddMonths(-1);
    filter.StartImportDate = begDate;
    filter.EndImportDate = endDate;
}
if (!filter.StartShipDate.HasValue && filter.EndShipDate.HasValue)
{
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
    DateTime begDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
    filter.StartShipDate = begDate;
    filter.EndShipDate = endDate;
}
```

I then installed the latest Acuminator and it gave me a warning not to set DAC fields from within the RowSelected handler so I removed the code and attempted to set it in the FieldDefaulting handler.  I can't seem to get the defaults to set correctly.

```
protected virtual void EDOrderReviewFilter_StartImportDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    EDOrderReviewFilter row = e.Row as EDOrderReviewFilter;
    if (row != null)
    {
        if (!row.StartImportDate.HasValue && row.EndImportDate.HasValue)
        {
            e.NewValue = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
protected virtual void EDOrderReviewFilter_StartShipDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    EDOrderReviewFilter row = e.Row as EDOrderReviewFilter;
    if (row != null)
    {
        if (!row.StartShipDate.HasValue && row.EndShipDate.HasValue)
        {
            e.NewValue = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do a date calculation in the PXDefault attribute, or what is wrong with my defaulting handlers?

Comment: does it work if you remove the e.cancel = true line from your defaults?

Comment: No.  The start dates still show up blank.

Comment: i would first test with the only thing in your default is the set of newvalue. as this is field defaulting it will run only once. You are checking for EndShipDate has a value however in the DAC it is after the field you are checking its value for which will not yet have a default. The field events typically run in the order of the fields in the DAC. If you need  the change of a field to trigger another you could use a PXFormulaAttribute with a Default<> to cause the defaulting event to fire again when the change of your field occurs. Alternatively change the order of fields in the dac

Comment: I changed my code to just set the default date based on the current date and not on the entered end date.  It appears to be working now.  It works without setting e.cancel = true.  I had read that you needed that when overriding the default.  When is that required?

Comment: i don't know that it is necessary. Cancel is usually indicating you dont want the event to continue in the chain of events. Maybe in field defaulting it indicates to not process any other defaulting events. But good question. I have not used it myself for field defaulting events. I think the key here is to just know the order of the fields as they are processed is as they exist in the DAC. If you moved your field placement around the code you had might work for the field defaulting events (just remove the cancel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Brendan's help, this is what I ended up with.

```
    protected virtual void EDOrderReviewFilter_StartImportDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValue = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
    }
    protected virtual void EDOrderReviewFilter_EndImportDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValue = DateTime.Today;
    }
    protected virtual void EDOrderReviewFilter_StartShipDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValue = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
    }
    protected virtual void EDOrderReviewFilter_EndShipDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValue = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
    }
```

Since there are no PXDefault attributes on the columns the cancel was not required.  Sometimes simpler is better!